# List comprehension- Multiple inputs

Tags: input

I am a beginner , trying to understand how list comprehension for multiple input works.
Can someone explain how the below code works?

x,y = [int(x) for x in input("Enter the value ").split()]
print(x,y)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually is not directly related to list comprehensions but instead a concept called "sequence unpacking", which applies to any [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) (`list`, `tuple`, `range`). What is happening here is that the user input is expected to be two whitespace-separated values. The `split` call will split the user input on the whitespace, returning a `list` of size 2. Then, the list comprehension is looping over each element of this `split`-produced list and converting each one to an `int`. Thus, the list comprehension will return a `list` of length 2, and each of its elements will be "unpacked" separately into the `x` and `y` variables on the left-hand side of the assignment operator. Here is an excerpt from the Data Structures section of the Python tutorial that explains sequence unpacking:

> The statement t = 12345, 54321, 'hello!' is an example of tuple packing: the values 12345, 54321 and 'hello!' are packed together in a tuple. The reverse operation is also possible:

```
>>> x, y, z = t
```

> This is called, appropriately enough, sequence unpacking and works for
> any sequence on the right-hand side. Sequence unpacking requires that
> there are as many variables on the left side of the equals sign as
> there are elements in the sequence. Note that multiple assignment is
> really just a combination of tuple packing and sequence unpacking.
>
> Note that *this only works if the user input is of length 2, else the
> sequence unpacking will not work and will result in an error.*